# Use DBT Targets Dynamically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, dbt

I have a dbt project that has a single profile with two targets in my profiles.yml:

```
my_project:
  target: target_a
  outputs:
    target_a: 
      ...
    target_b: 
      ...
```

I have a file structure that looks like:

```
int/
  folder_a/
    _models__folder_a.yml
    int_a_sql_job.sql
    int_a_sql_job2.sql
  folder_b/
    _models__folder_b.yml
    int_b_sql_job.sql
```

`target_a` is the default target and is used for `folder_a` jobs, which is what I want. However, for all jobs in `folder_b` I need to use the `target_b` target. Passing `--target target_b` in the command line works, but I need this to be overridden from within the codebase itself, specifically in the `_models__folder_b`. How do I do that?

EDIT:

The reason I need this: I want all jobs in `folder_b` to write to a different schema, but that schema needs to be dynamic. When I'm running this on my staging server, `folder_a` needs to write to `folder_a_staging_schema` and `folder_b` needs to write to `folder_b_staging_schema`. When I'm running this on my prod server, `folder_a` needs to write to `folder_a_schema` and `folder_b` needs to write to `folder_b_schema`.

I'm realizing now that dbt probably cannot do this, cause dbt uses one single target for the entire duration of running a single command.

I'm open to other ideas, but I want to be able to `dbt run` and everything builds to the correct schema (i.e. not running jobs separately with the --target flag)

Answer (score 1):

why dont you just add a different schema for each folder? like

```
---staging (for all other folders)
     |---staging A (folder A)
     |---staging B (folder B)
```

and in the dbt_project.yml

```
staging:
    +schema: staging
    folder_a:
        +schema: staging_folder_a
    folder_b:
        +schema: staging_folder_b
```